# SIGSEGV in my C split()

Tags: c

```
char ** split(char * s, char * separator) {
  char ** words = malloc(sizeof(char *));   
  int i = 0;                    
  char * word = strtok(strdup(s), separator);
  while (word) {
    words = realloc(words, sizeof(char *) * (i + 1));   
    words[i] = malloc(strlen(word) + 1);
    strcpy(words[i++], word);
    word = strtok(NULL, separator);
  }
  words = realloc(words, sizeof(char *) * (i + 1));
  words[i] = NULL;
  return words;
}
```

This function systematically bugs when trying to compare the last non-null element like so:

```
char ** p = split("a b c d e f", " ");
while(*p++);
printf("%i", strcmp(*--p, "&"));
```

with this gdb output:

> Program received signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.
>   __strcmp_sse42 () at ../sysdeps/x86_64/multiarch/strcmp-sse42.S:164 164   ../sysdeps/x86_64/multiarch/strcmp-sse42.S: No such file or
>   directory.

When I google "__strcmp_sse42", I find a million bugs "SIGSEGV in [insert big package name]" which is not very encouraging, yet the chances are I made a beginner mistake, can someone spot it?

Thanks!

PS: here is a link : http://pastebin.com/Q2qw2VPL  to minimal compilable code replicating the problem.

Comment: You should run this in a debugger (or liberally add print statements) to determine the values of variables at the crash point.

Comment: I did, and every value is perfect. I finally understood this was a glibc file, opened it to line 164, which is assembly, and I have no clue to assembly :/

Comment: If you are invoking a seg-fault in `strcmp`, then there are two possiblities: (A) there is a bug in `strcmp`; (B) every value is *not* perfect ;)  Most likely cause is that you are not passing it a valid C string.

Comment: Indeed it seems *--p brings NULL - how could it pass the while loop?

Comment: You should inspect the values of `p` (and `*p`) through the course of your program.

Comment: I really don't understand it, it seems that the idiom while(*p++); goes 2 indexes after the last non null element of the table. Whereas while(*p) p++; does only go one index after.

Comment: THink about it. In the second one, the p++ is inside the loop. In the first, it does it during the check to do the loop. The answer below is correct.

Comment: duh, too late for me I guess, thank you people

Comment: When GDB stops, type `bt` at GDB's command prompt. This will show you stack trace. You then should go to the stack frame where your code last occurs in the stack trace. Let's assume it's frame 1, so you type `fr 1`. That will put GDB into the context of your while loop where you can use commands like `print` to investigate variables.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is here:

```
while(*p++);
```

This increments `p` *after* testing `*p` for zero. (More precisely, first it increments `p`, then it tests the old value of `*p` for zero.) If `*p` was zero, `p` has been incremented one beyond the `NULL` before the loop stops.

```
printf("%i", strcmp(*--p, "&"));
```

Here you decrement `p` once and then feed `*p` to `strcmp`, where it is `NULL`, crashing the program.
The fix is simple, first test for zero, then increment:

```
while (*p) ++p;
```

Comment: Yep. I was typing up just that.